# C++ Logger Performance and Portability

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx, log4cplus, glog

I'm writing a C++ application, that I have to deploy to a server in the future (maybe as a node.js C++ module). 
I really need a logging library that help me during the development process. 
Now I'm using log4cxx, but I need the code to be portable, so I prefer to have a source file to include in the project. I also need a performing C++ logger, that does not slow down the application in both case with logging turned on and off. Can anyone help me with this choice? My options are:

1. **Log4cplus**: simple and easy to use and extend. But *performance*?
2. **Google-Glog**: easiest to use and very very fast. But I need to compile it and it use system flag, I wonder if it is a problem when I use it with node.js.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the log4cxx uses Apache runtime as its base so ,portability is not an issue with log4cxx. Also it provides macros for optimized logging. Is there anyother reason you want to shift from log4cxx?

Comment: Because I prefer to have a class that I can embed in my project and compile as a unique executable. Google-Glog is a choice because I can access the src file.

Comment: You can have a statically linked application with log4cxx, it requires the apr, aprutils at its dependencies. even with LOG4CXX you have the following for source files and line number with the following macro:  LOG4CXX_LOCATION . For the Google-Glog , I havent personally used it so can't help.